# How to restrict the Tridion UI tags for a particular component?

Tags: 2011, experience-manager

I am using Tridion User Interface 2011. Tridion UI related tags are coming from the user defined compound TBB **Component Finish Actions** which is associated with all the CTs, which internally holds the OOB TBB **Enable inline editing for content**. Following are the parameters for **Enable inline editing for content** TBB.

```
        <CPHtmlTag>uicp</CPHtmlTag>
        <FieldHtmlTag>uicpfield</FieldHtmlTag>
```

By using this TBB in every Component template result in Tridion UI tags in the rendered content.

The requirement is if the **Enable for inline editing** check box in CT is cleared for a particular component, Tridion UI related tags should not rendered in the output content.

I given a try by clearing the check box, publishing the CT and previewing the content, still I can find the Tridion UI related tags in the source.

Provide me an approach whether to pass any extra parameters? If so please provide the parameter which need to be set. Through some light how can i find the existing the parameters for the OOB TBB.

Answer (score 4):

A few hints:

- There is no OOTB "Component Finish Actions", this seems to be something that was added by the implementer(s)
- Disabling inline editing for a CT will just stop Experience Manager from showing editable areas (borders and so on), not stop the tags from being output - this allows you to turn it on or off without republishing, which is a good thing!

If you don't want tags in the CT's output then you should not use the `Enable inline editing` TBB in your Component Template.

**EDIT**

Here's how I would "solve" this issue:

1. Create a new TBB, call it "Standard Component Finish Actions Without Inline Editing"
2. Add all TBBs of your current "Component Finish Actions" TBB to this new one *except* for `Enable inline editing`
3. Modify the existing "Component Finish Actions" to include the new TBB, and the Inline Editing TBB

Now you have successfully decoupled `Enable Inline Editing` from your `Component Finish Actions` without having to modify any existing CT. In a CT where you don't need to enable inline editing, use the `Standard Component Finish Actions Without Inline Editing` TBB, and for all other CTs continue using the current `Component Finish Actions`.

**EDIT 2**

This checkbox prevents content rendered with this Component Template from being edited. It does not remove the tags nor does it remove the borders. If you are trying to remove this information from the rendered component presentation then you must **not** use the "Enable inline editing" TBB in your Component Template.

Comment: Thanks for hints. I modified the question. But the "Component Finish Actions" is a compound template designed in such way that it is useful in every CT. So is there any way to restrict the tags from output without modifying the "Component Finish Actions" compound TBB?

Comment: As far as I know, no. If you include the inline editing TBB and the current target is configured for inline editing, the tags will be added.

Comment: Is there any way to add the "Enable inline editing for content" TBB dynamically based on the state of "Enable for inline editing" check box?

Comment: Again - not that I know of. You are going in circles around the easy solution... editing my answer.

Comment: Nice idea Nuno. That's thinking outside the (check) box!

Comment: @nuno-linhares Yes your solution will solve my problem. But many(around a hundred ) CTs uses the "Component Finish Actions" TBB. As you said earlier disabling the Enable Inline Editing will stop Experience Manager from showing editable areas. I worked on that line but I am able to edit a component in Tridion UI even after disabling the Enable Inline Editing option for a CT. Please correct me where I am doing mistake.

Comment: The changes I proposed make sure you don't need to change existing CTs. I will double check on the content being editable (i.e., I'll test it on my system)

Comment: @nuno-linhares I know you are so busy. Can you please have a look at the check box issue in your system.

Comment: Just tested, works as expected - the component presentation shows a lock on the top left corner, and if I click on it it says "Editing disabled - Editing this content has been explicitly diabled for all users"

Comment: Editable areas are still rendered in Experience Manager even after disabling inline editing for a CT. Even after republishing the component and page; it still works the same way. Please let me know whether i need to implement any checks for the check-box to work as expected. **Steps done:**
1. Added a new content component.
2. Mapped the component to the Component Template with RenderComponentField method to render the fields with Tridion UI tags(<span class=\"tridionuicpfield\"..).
3. Unchecked the 'Enable for inline editing' check-box in Component Template.
4. Published the component and the

Comment: Misunderstanding on the functionality then. Yes, it will still render the tags, and yes you will still see the borders. You will not be able to edit the content. If you don't want to see the borders then you CANNOT include the "Enable for inline editing" TBB in your CT.